# organize Java code into packages is equals to architecture patterns/style?

Tags: java, architecture

I'm so confused, I was searching about best practices to stucture my project, I mean the best way to organize Java code into packages. Also, I read about architecture styles and architecture patterns where some pages say they are the same and others say they are different,so my doubt comes here, first, architecture style and architecture pattern are the same?. Then, when you are talking about organizing your java code into packages is the same than when you say: "I am looking for a best architecture patten for my java project". I really need to understand this, I have been reading and reading and I still don't get it. and finally sorry if you can't understand what I post here, my english is bad and I need to practice more.

Comment: Maybe your question will be better received here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will post it there.

Comment: @CalvinNunes when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @RonaldoGeldres It's been awhile, so just a reminder to review my answer and mark it if it answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://herbertograca.com/2017/07/28/architectural-styles-vs-architectural-patterns-vs-design-patterns/

Architectural Style:

> Architectural styles tell us, in very broad strokes, how to organise
>   our code. It’s the highest level of granularity and it specifies
>   layers, high-level modules of the application and how those modules
>   and layers interact with each other, the relations between them.
>   Examples of Architectural Styles:
>
> ```
> Component-based
> Monolithic application
> Layered
> Pipes and filters
> Event-driven
> Publish-subscribe
> Plug-ins
> Client-server
> Service-oriented
> ```

Architectural Pattern:

> A pattern is a recurring solution to a recurring problem. In the case
>   of Architectural Patterns, they solve the problems related to the
>   Architectural Style. For example, “what classes will we have and how
>   will they interact, in order to implement a system with a specific set
>   of layers“, or “what high-level modules will have in our
>   Service-Oriented Architecture and how will they communicate“, or “how
>   many tiers will our Client-server Architecture have“.
>
> Architectural Patterns have an extensive impact on the code base, most
>   often impacting the whole application either horizontally (ie. how to
>   structure the code inside a layer) or vertically (ie. how a request is
>   processed from the outer layers into the inner layers and back).
>   Examples of Architectural Patterns:
>
> ```
> Three-tier
> Microkernel
> Model-View-Controller
> Model-View-ViewModel
> ```

To me this represents a similar dichotomy to Interface and Implementation at the class level.

In other words, the Style is the goal and the Pattern is how you achieve that goal

Java packages serve 2 purposes that relate to this. They are used to organized your code and they provide an encapsulation at the library level by the use of public vs package-private.

If you go with a client-server style, then you will need a package for the server and a package for the client that can be used independently.
The server and client will likely share common POJOs that you'll want to put in a package that is shared between them.

If you go with a plugin style like then you'll need a package for the common interface and loader but any implementations will go in their own package. Compare with SLF4J and it's implementations.
Both the plugin loading package and each plugin implementation will need to share a small package that contains the plugin interface.

Now if you choose a service style, then you may only have one top level package for your whole service, but you might choose to organize sub-packages based on different domains, e.g. a package for core logic that can be unit tested without IO concerns and a package that deals with interacting with IO. In other words, the core interface is just concerned with objects and methods, but the IO package deals with parsing requests and printing responses.